# Including QuickDialog into Xcode 4.2 Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, include, xcode4.2

I try to include QuickDialog into one of my projects and just can't get it to work.
I did the following:

1. downloaded it from [github](https://github.com/escoz/quickdialog)
2. copied it into my project directory
3. drag and droped the QuickDialog.xcodeproj file downloaded from github
   previously from Finder to my project
4. in the Build Phases, Added QuickDialog (the lib, not the example app)
   as a Target Dependency
5. in the Link Binary With Libraries section, added the libQuickDialog.a
   library (this turns red actually don't know why)
6. In my Prefix.pch file, add: `#import <QuickDialog/QuickDialog.h>`

cause this didn't work I also tried the following:

1. added -Objc and -all_load to my "Other Linker Flags"
2. added `$(SOURCE_ROOT)/escoz-QuickDialog-b5f67f1` to "User Header
   Search Path"

this also didn´t work I always get the error `QuickDialog/QuickDialog.h file not found` at the line `#import <QuickDialog/QuickDialog.h>`
What do I do wrong?

Comment: with xcode 4.5.2 i've gone through the steps outlined here:
http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog i've made sure the quotes are manually typed in. i've manually typed the "${PROJECT_DIR}/QuickDialog" line in. i still get file not found in the .pch file.

Comment: @joshk I am trying to ad it to an Xcode 4.5.2 project right now and also getting same error. Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to this problems are, as posted in the comments, the quotes on `“${PROJECT_DIR}/QuickDialog”` as you can see there two different quotes.

The solution is to NOT copy it from the documentary, instead just type it yourself and your are fine.

It should look like this: `"${PROJECT_DIR}/QuickDialog"`

Thats the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Did you not do *exactly* these steps too, from the [documentation](http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog):

> Locate the “User Header Search Paths” setting, and set the Release value to “${PROJECT_DIR}/QuickDialog” (including quotes!) and check the “Recursive” check box.
>
> The Debug value should already be set, but if it’s not, change that as well.
>
> Also locate the “Always Search User Paths” value and set it to YES.
> Finally, find the “Other Linker Flags” option, and add the value “-ObjC” (no quotes).

These instructions do work.

Comment: hi @petert, I did EXACTLY the steps posted in the documentation and it does NOT work I don't know why.

Comment: your are absolutely right de documentation works BUT there is one little mistake that caused my problem `“${PROJECT_DIR}/QuickDialog”` these are the WRONG quotes!!!! just typed it yourself with normal quotes and everything is fine. thanks for your help

Comment: I have fixed the quotes on the site, hopefully this won't be a problem to others in the future!

Comment: Thanks Eduardo. This is really a taff one to find. Hope in the future nobody has this problem again. QuickDialog is the best!!! Thank you so much for it!