# QuickDialog/QuickDialog.h file not found xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, quickdialog

Hy, I want to use the QuickDialog library but gives me error.

The step that I made:

1. download it from github
2. copy the directory into my project's directory
3. add QuickDialog.xcodeproject
4. my project --> Build Phrases:
             Target dipendencies: add QuickDialog
              link Binary : add libQuickDialog.a
5. include in mi file Prefix.phc :#import
6. my project --> Build Settings:
              Other linker flags: -ObjC
              User header search paths : "${PROJECT_DIR}/QuickDialog" and check the box
              always serach user path : YES
7. run

But give me the error: 
QuickDialog/QuickDialog.h file not found

What is wrong???

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

If you put this: "${PROJECT_DIR}/QuickDialog"

and you try to import "QuickDialog/QuickDialog.h"
that means that he goes in directory: "${PROJECT_DIR}/QuickDialog/QuickDialog/QuickDialog.h" ?

Did you try to put just: "QuickDialog.h" ?

EDIT: The solution is here: [Including QuickDialog into Xcode 4.2 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308297/including-quickdialog-into-xcode-4-2-project)